# Trying to fix my Laravel 7 Eloquent relationship with three tables (Users, Profiles, Countries)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to create a relationship between my 'users', 'profiles' and 'countries' table.

- Users table has the columns: id - name - email - password
- Profiles table has the columns: id - user_id - country_id
- Countries table has the columns: id - name - code

The problem is that currently my code is matching a user id directly to the id in the country table (user one gets country one, user two - country two, etc). But what I would like to do is match the country_id in the profiles table to the country id in the countries table (so user 1 has a profile with a country_id of 5 which get the county with the id of 5 in the countries table). Any help correcting this would be much appreiated.

My User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, Commenter;

    public function country()
    {
        // if I remove 'id' I get the error "Unknown column 'countries.user_id'"
        return $this->hasOne(Country::class, 'id');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
    
}
```

My Profile Model

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

My Country Model

```
class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

My UserController

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function singleUserData($userId) 
    {
        $singleUserData= User::where('id', $userId)->with('country','profile')->get();

        return view('single-user-data', ['singleUserData' => $singleUserData]);
    }

    public function allUsersData() {
        
        $allUsersData = User::with('profile','country')->get();

        return view('all-users-data', ['allUsersData' => $allUsersData]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relations are slightly out.

Your Profile model is correct - each Profile belongs to one Country and belongs to one User.

It's your User and your Country models which aren't correct. Your User doesn't 'haveOne' Country as there's no direct relationship between Users and Countries - it goes **through** the Profile model. So what you're looking for there is, instead, that your User uses the '**hasOneThrough**' relationship to find its Country.

And, in reverse, each Country will have (potentially) many Users, but not directly - again through the Profile model, so your Country needs to use the '**hasManyThrough**' relationship to find its Users.

Comment: I added to the Country model ```public function user(){return $this->hasManyThrough(Country::class, Profile::class);}``` and to the User Model ```public function user(){return $this->hasOneThrough(Country::class, Profile::class);}``` but i get an error "Unknown column 'countries.profile_id'" I've been fiddling around with adding additonal arguments to hasOneThrough ex: ```(Country::class, Profile::class, 'country_id', 'user_id', 'id', 'id')``` but best I can do is get a country value of null for a user.

Comment: I hate having to work those out, but going on past experience, I think you should be looking at : 
    (Country::class, Profile::class, 'user_id', 'id', 'id', 'country_id', 'profiles')

Comment: Yup that works! Thank you. Can I ask how did you know to add an extra argument to the hasOneThrough? The laravel docs on this ends with, "The fifth argument is the local key, while the sixth argument is the local key of the intermediate model".  I would never have known to add a seventh argument without you showing me.

Comment: I think, actually, that it's superfluous (it's the table name, but it should get that from your Profile model if it's anything unusual (it expects a Model named "Profile" to have a table named "profiles" by default, but I tend to put the table name into the model automatically anyway). I think your issue was that user_id and country_id arguments were in the wrong place / order.